# Maximum voltage in series circuit

Tags: voltage, serial, laser

I have a set of laser-modules with integrated drivers that I want to setup in series. The datasheet says the maximum voltage for a module is 3.3V. Two run two modules in series I doubled the voltage from 3V to 5.8V, otherwise they would not light up. Does this damage the modules or is the voltage shared evenly between the modules?

The datasheet is available here http://www.egismos.com/laser-modules/IR-laser-module-D985030L.pdf

Comment: There is no guarantee that the voltage will be shared equally between modules.  Connect them in parallel to a 3.3 V source.

Comment: given identical modules, the voltage is divide up equally in series circuits. since these are basically LEDs we're talking about, that works, but is less than ideal because of manufacturing defects, regulation failures, temp differences and more, all conspiring to deliver non-egalitarian power. Parrellel shares voltage and distributes current, so it's the better way to go, provided you have some current regulation or at least limiting.

Comment: @dandavis "With integrated drivers" means they probably aren't just LEDs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will connect them in parallel than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given no clue, part number or datasheet link.

If the laser module regulates the current in an analog fashion internally then the one with the lower current requirement will have a higher "resistance" and more than half the voltage will be dropped across it.

If the laser module regulates the current using some sort of PWM then the current waveform will follow the PWM and alternate between low and high. Since both are in series and not synchronised they will choke off current to each other when the PWM is off.

> Does this damage the modules or is the voltage shared evenly between the modules?

The voltage is unlikely to be shared equally. Damage is likely.